# is there any way to iterate two lists parallely in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

Consider this code in java

```
for(int i=0,j=0;i<list1.size() && j<list2.size();i++,j++){

//do something

}
```

Can we do the similar thing in sightly? I tried best on my level but I couldn't find a way to do it. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this kind of iteration and this is intended (in order to avoid putting your business logic in the HTL/Sightly template). You should instead invoke an Use-Api object which applies this logic and returns a collection of tuples from the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer posted by Vlad, You could either use

- Sling Models
- WCMUse class
- server side javascript to perform such business logic

I would say it is better to use nodejs for such simple problems as it is more productive, easy to write and lives in the same folder as the sightly/HTL code.

For example, if your component name is 'componentA'
your HTL/sightly code is componentA.html residing inside componentA folder
and your business logic can be componentA.js residing in the same folder.

```
use(function() {
    /*
        Business logic
    */
    return {
        name: valueName,
        list: listObject
    };
});
```

Sling Models are very effective when you need to perform business logic using injected properties and resources. For example, a component that has several primitive and derived (from resource) properties.